# Enable segmented controller indexes according to user defaults

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to enable `UISegmentedController` indexes according to `UserDefaults`. But my problem I do not know how to enable indexes if the function returns true.

I have one master viewcontroller, that has the `segmentedController`.

Lets say I have 4 indexes. 0 is enabled and 1,2,3,4 are disabled. Now if score is `>= value`, I would like to enable index 1.

I know that I can enable and disable segmentAt like this: `segmentedControl.setEnabled(true, forSegmentAt: 1) // can also be false` but how can I implement it into the function.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
class func checkIfEligibleForNextDifficulty(key: String, score: Int) -> Bool{
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

        if userDefaults.integer(forKey: key) >= score{
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
```

And I am using it like this:

```
if Util.checkIfEligibleForNextDifficulty(key: "diff2", score: 8){
     //Here I want to enable the index 1
}
```

What is the best approach for this kind of thins? Should I declare some globals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could model a concept like a `Level` and a Level can be created from a `score`. Therefore when you initialize a `Level` with a score, automatically you will infer the level.

Then, given that the Level will be an int enum will help you to match it with the index of your segmented control.

For enabling the levels according the score, you could create a function like below.

```
enum Level: Int {
    case beginner
    case medium
    case advanced
    case expert
}

//MARK: Score & Enabling levels

extension Level {

    init(score: Int) {
        switch score {
        case 1..<8: self = .beginner
        case 8..<20: self = .medium
        case 20..<100: self = .advanced
        case 100..<Int.max: self = .expert
        default: self = .beginner
        }
    }

    func enabledLevels() -> [Level] {
        switch self {
        case .beginner: return [.beginner]
        case .medium: return [.beginner, .medium]
        case .advanced: return [.beginner, .medium, .advanced]
        case .expert: return [.beginner, .medium, .advanced, .expert]
        }
    }
}
```

As an exercise, try to adapt my solution for adding the UserDefaults, which won't be difficult.

Hope it helps and solve your problem. :)

Comment: Can you explain, how would you enable or disable the segmented controller index using approach like this? And if I want to use userdefaults, I assume I just have to add it inside initing? And btw, I can not use this since I have viewcontroller for every level. And every level has it's own userDefault value for score :(.

Comment: A level can have a dependency with the user defaults, so once you want to initialize a Level from a score, you will query the user defaults base on your needs. 

Imagine you have this `Level(score: 45)` then you can enable the levels like this:

`let aLevel = Level(score: 45)
aLevel.enabledLevels().forEach { level in
 segmentedControl.setEnabled(true, forSegmentAt: level.rawValue)
}`